# iPhone app crashing being killed in background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm making this app with which the user can record and play sound and send it to the server. However when it goes to the background and i kill the app (double tap on the home screen and remove it from there) it will crash when i try to open it back up with only this in the console:

```
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
```

Does anyone know why it is doing this and how i can solve this? If you need any more information just ask for it and I will provide it asap!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: does it occur when you're running in debug mode ? Maybe it's the problem.. Just quit the debug and start it on phone or simulator like a normal application start (click app icon), then try to get it in backround mode with double tab home button..

Comment: Nope it will do this anyway. Even if i install it, remove the usb wire and then try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand you're running your app in debug mode (connected to Xcode). When you close the app via the home button the OS sends SIGKILL to the process and that is why the debug session is also terminated.

So your application doesn't crash.

Comment: Yea.. that was kinda dumb of me not to think of that. Well thanks anyway for the quick reply!